# CMake cannot copy library to test folder in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, copy, visual-studio-2019

I've the following project folder structure:

```
project
|-CMakeLists.txt
|
|-src
|  |-mybiglib
|     |-CMakeLists.txt
|
|-tests
   |-mybiglibtest
      |-CMakeLists.txt
```

I've the following `CMakeLists.txt` for a unit test project. The library that I want to test is `mybiglib`, and is built correctly in another `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10.0)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()
project (mybiglibtest)

message (STATUS "Building project ${PROJECT_NAME}")

set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/tests)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
unset (Boost_INCLUDE_DIR CACHE)
unset (Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS CACHE)
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework log system REQUIRED)

include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set (TEST_SRC
  stdafx.cpp
  Test1.cpp
  )

add_executable ( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${TEST_SRC})
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} mybiglib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
add_custom_command (OUTPUT "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/mybiglib.dll" COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:mybiglib> "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")
```

I have the project opened in Visual Studio 2019.

If I execute the command `Build All`, the problem is that the .dll `mybiglib.dll` is not copied in `tests` folder, so tests don't start.

Instead, if I execute the command `Rebuild All` the library is copied in test folder, but obviously rebuilding all every time is time consuming.

How can I copy the library in the test folder also when building and not only when rebuilding?

Comment: Your `add_custom_command` has OUTPUT `mybiglib.dll`, but none *target* depends on that output. Without such target `add_custom_command` is *useless*.

Comment: You should not copy the library, so your last step should be removed. When executing the test, just make sure that the path where the library is located can be found by the test.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've tried to add both `DEPENDS mybiglib` and `DEPENDS mybiglibtest` but none of them works. How should I modify the command?

Comment: You should add **another target**, which `DEPENDS` on the command's `OUTPUT`. Adding `DEPENDS` option to the command adds reverse dependency, which is not what you need.